# Error message for failed new ImageIcon(url)

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I try to load an image with:

`ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(url);`

if I query the load status:

`imageIcon.getImageLoadStatus();` 

it returns `MediaTracker.ERRORED`

Is there a way to get an error message saying what the problem was?

Comment: Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org), so we can see how you actually coded your URL.

Comment: `new ImageIcon("http://sstatic.net/so/favicon.ico")` as URL should do the trick. Note that I don't want to know why a particular case fails (in this case because Java can't parse .ico), but how to generally get a decent error message when it fails for whatever cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the image via alternate methods.  That might give you better feedback:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(url);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
```

Comment: I still want to use the background-loading feature the Java ImageIcon API supports. I could use MediaTracker directly but it seems to have the same poblem, ie you can check for failure, but not get a reason why out of it.

Comment: I am suggesting that you try alternate implementations to see if they fail as well.  Then you may get a better idea on why your desired implementation fails.